# R : Generate a dataframe from list of possible values

Tags: r

```
newdata <- as_tibble( # valid values shown below
  dvcat="10-24",        # "1-9" "10-24"   "25-39"   "40-54"   "55+"  
  seatbelt="none",      # "none"   "belted"  
  frontal="frontal",    # "notfrontal" "frontal"
  sex="f",              # "f" "m"
  ageOFocc=22,          # age in years, 16-97
  yearVeh=2002,         # year of vehicle, 1955-2003
  airbag="none",        # "none"   "airbag"   
  occRole="pass"        # "driver" "pass"
)
```

```
  dvcat seatbelt frontal sex ageOFocc yearVeh airbag occRole
1 10-24     none frontal   f       22    2002   none    pass
```

I want to generate the possible combination of the variables above and put them into a tibble dataframe.

For example, let's say I want to have a dataset with 3 rows. Randomly the value will be pick to create a new row.

```
  dvcat seatbelt   frontal sex ageOFocc yearVeh airbag occRole
1 10-24     none   frontal   f       22    2002   none    pass
2 25-39     none   frontal   m       54    2010   none    drive
3 40-54     belted frontal   f       14    2016   airbag    driver
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have a `list` of values to pick, then use

```
library(purrr)
map_dfr(lst1, ~ sample(.x, 3, replace = TRUE))
# A tibble: 3 x 8
#  dvcat seatbelt frontal    sex   ageOFocc yearVeh airbag occRole
#  <chr> <chr>    <chr>      <chr>    <int>   <int> <chr>  <chr>  
#1 40-54 none     notfrontal f           71    1997 none   driver 
#2 40-54 none     frontal    m           87    1974 airbag driver 
#3 25-39 belted   notfrontal m           56    2001 none   driver
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
data.frame(lapply(lst1, sample, size = 3, replace = TRUE))
```

#### data

```
lst1 <- list(dvcat = c("1-9", "10-24", "25-39", "40-54", "55+"), 
  seatbelt = c("none", 
"belted"), frontal = c("notfrontal", "frontal"), sex = c("f", 
"m"), ageOFocc = 16:97, yearVeh = 1955:2003, airbag = c("none", 
"airbag"), occRole = c("driver", "pass"))
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to share your suggestion!